# Fast PWM working with int main(void) but not with void setup()

Tags: arduino-mega, pwm

board: Arduino Mega (ATMEGA2560)

I want to generate pulses using timer1 configured as Fast PWM, this is my code which works fine:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
//void setup()
{

  DDRB |= (1 << DDB5) | (1 << DDB6); // PWM outputs


  ICR1 = 0x7FFF;  // TOP
  OCR1A = 0x3FFF; // 50% of ICR1
  OCR1B = 0x3FFF; // 50% of ICR1

  TCCR1A |= (1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1B1);
  TCCR1A |= (1 << WGM11);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12) | (1 << WGM13);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);

}

void loop() {

}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work if I use `void setup()` instead of `int main(void)`. I'm working with arduino IDE 1.8.2 and always used void setup(), in this case I used int main(void) because it is used in some turorials I found like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Yqf_cugwE

EDIT: When I say that it doesn't work, what happens is that instead of having PWM signals I just have a constant 5V output in both OC1A and OC1B pins

Comment: Try using `=` instead of `|=`.

Comment: Using `=` instead of `|=` I have now a 0V output instead of 5V. I tried to initialize `TCCR1A = 0;` and `TCCR1B = 0;` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't define your own `main()`, your program will be linked with
the `main()` provided by the Arduino core library, which roughly looks
like this (I am simplifying a little bit):

```c++
int main(void)
{
    init();      // Arduino core initialization
    setup();     // user's initialization
    for (;;)
        loop();  // user's main loop
}
```

The [core's `init()` function](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.2/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L241) configures Timer 1 for 8-bit phase
correct PWM at 490 Hz, which means that, by the time your `setup()`
runs, the timer's control registers are not in their default state
anymore, and some of their bits are already set to 1. If you then
update these registers using the `|=` operator, you end up with a mix of
the core's configuration and your own.

This can be fixed either by zeroing these registers first or, more
simply, by setting their values with the `=` operator, which has the
effect or setting *every* bit of those registers to the value you want.

The following works whether you use or not the Arduino core library:

```c++
#ifdef NOCORE
int main(void)
#else
void setup()
#endif
{
    DDRB   = _BV(PB5) | _BV(PB6);
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)
           | _BV(COM1B1)
           | _BV(WGM11);
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)
           | _BV(WGM13)
           | _BV(CS10);
    ICR1   = 0x7fff;  // TOP
    OCR1A  = 0x3fff;  // 50% of ICR1
    OCR1B  = 0x3fff;  // 50% of ICR1
}

#ifndef NOCORE
void loop(){}
#endif
```

Note that:

1. The control registers are *set* (`=`) rather than just modified with
   `|=`
2. The mode is set before the output compare registers. This is because
   setting the output compare registers does not work well when the timer
   is in an 8-bit mode.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the order in which the timer is set up could affect in some way, i had no idea.  With your code it still does not work for me, did you have a chance to test it?

Comment: @Mr.C: I tested it (and it works) on an Uno. I had to change `DDRB` to `_BV(PB1) | _BV(PB2)` in order to fit the Uno's pinout. Note that on the previous version of my answer I mistakenly left the `DDRB` setting appropriate for the Uno.

Comment: After changing `DDRB to _BV(PB1) | _BV(PB2)` to the corresponding pins in MEga `DDRB to _BV(PB5) | _BV(PB6)` it works perfectly, i didnt notice that. Thank you so much @Edgar Bonet, after your explanation about the core's init function it is more clear for me now why it was not working with `void setup()`.